# Running a python script skipping thje pdb breakpoints

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

How to run a python script from the command line in a non-debug skipping the breakpoints, even though it has`pdb.set_trace()` breakpoints set in the script?

Comment: You could just modify the script to not have those `set_trace` calls, or put them in an `if` block.